# Prevent Meteor from quickly skimming all the elements in a collection just to show the latest one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I need to display the latest element of a collection. What I currently have is this function to get the latest value:

```
balance_values: function(){
  return Balance.find({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 1});
},
```

Then the the HTML is like:

```
<body>
{{#each balance_values}}
    {{> balance}}
  {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="balance">
  <h2>{{value}}</h2>
</template>
```

But with this, when I load the page, I see all the older values in that collection appear quickly until the latest value appears. What do I have to do to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Use findOne() to return the specific value you want.

```
<head>
   <title>hi</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> hi}}
</body>

<template name="hi">
  <p>Hi, {{person.name}}</p>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hi.helpers({

    'person':function(){
         return Names.findOne();
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Using return Balance.findOne({}, {sort: {date: -1}, limit: 1}); shows nothing on the HTML :/

Comment: Even without the {{#each}} in html?

Comment: Oh, I don't think you need the limit:1 part either. findOne returns 1.

Comment: But how do I call the function with the template without #each?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code returns a cursor and loops through each value in that cursor. You can either modify it to use fetch() to return a single document or just use [findOne()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone).

```
balance_value: function(){
Balance.findOne({}, {sort: {date: -1}});
}

<body>
{{#with balance_value}}
    {{> balance}}
{{/with}}
</body>

<template name="balance">
  <h2>{{balance_value.value}}</h2>
</template>
```